# Watching vuex state change from vuejs component

Tags: vue.js, vuex

I am new to both vue.js and vuex. I have a component that need to dispatch an action when a specific data is available in the state. How can I do this.

Example:

```
export default {
   name: 'MyComponent',
   computed: {
      targetItem() {
         return this.$store.getters.getTarget(this.$route.params.id);
      }
   }
}
```

In the example above i would like to dispatch a new action on the store when `targetItem` has a value. This is so i can trigger an ajax request via a vuex action to collect more data about `targetItem`

Thanks

Comment: What have you already tried and what's not working as you expected?

Comment: Your use-case is very unclear to me. Are you looking for something like in this [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/awolf2904/0txhcvae/)? Please add more details to your questions. What are you planning to do with the action? Is it sending an ajax request, does it change state etc.?

Answer (score 1):

I eventually found a solution that work

```
export default {
   name: 'MyComponent',
   computed: {
      targetItem() {
         return this.$store.getters.getTarget(this.$route.params.id);
     }
   },
   watch: {
      shop (newVal, oldVal) {
         if(!!newVal && !oldVal) {
            const {targetItem} = this;           
            this.$store.dispatch('ACTION_NAME',{targetItem});
         }
      }
   }
}
```

Thanks